# Which is correct for displaying installed updates: WMIC or Systeminfo?

Tags: windows-7, wmic, patch, system-info

Am applying a "critical" Microsoft patch (KB4499164) to a number of remote Windows 7 (32-bit) PCs.  My ONLY option to access these PCs is via SSH and SFTP.

I used a batch script to apply this patch overnight to nine systems as a pilot.  Three of the PCs list the patch when I use either the **wmic qfe** command or the **systeminfo** command.  On the remaining PCs, the **wmic qfe** command shows the patch as installed, but the **systeminfo** command does NOT list the patch.

Which one is correct?  How do I know for sure if the patch applied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `WMIC qfe list` will return correct results. The `systeminfo` command will not. My notes indicate it's limited to displaying 246 hotfixes (which are [not the same as updates](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ntdebugging/2008/10/21/windows-hotfixes-and-updates-how-do-they-work/)), but I can't find a source for that. This Microsoft KB [support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2644427/systeminfo-exe-does-not-display-all-updates-in-windows-server-2003) does say:

> When using SystemInfo.exe in Windows Server 2003 to display a list of installed hotfixes, some hotfixes may not be listed if over 200 are installed....There is a buffer size limitation that does not allow all system update hotfixes to be displayed.

However it only mentions Server 2003.

Bottom line, use the WMIC command to get a complete list of installed updates.